# @Service Spring as Managed property of ManagedBean class in jsf is null

Tags: spring, maven, jsf

I've a webapp using JSF + Spring + Maven + JBoss (java 8).

I've a class ManagedBean with a property ManagedProperty which is a service spring.
In remote debugging I checked that the service is not injected and is null.
No errors in console (or server.log).

java class

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
...
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loggedUserSession}")
    private ILoggedUserSession loggedUserSession;

    public String getUserLogin() {
        return loggedUserSession.getUser();
    }

    public ILoggedUserSession getLoggedUserSession() {
        return loggedUserSession;
    }

    public void setLoggedUserSession(ILoggedUserSession loggedUserSession) {
        this.loggedUserSession = loggedUserSession;
    }
...
}
```

service java class

```
@Service("loggedUserSession")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class LoggedUserSessionImpl implements ILoggedUserSession, Serializable {...}
```

pom.xml

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

In the applicationContext.xml i mapped <context:component-scan ... /> and

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:conf.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I noticed the error at runtime.

I checked in web.xml, faces-config, applicationContext.xml and pom.xml but I didn't find anything strange.